# Vim does not take umlauts as word characters

Tags: unicode

When I write a German text containing something like `abücd` for instance and to a `dw` in front, it will only delete the `ab` since it does not interpret `ü` as a word character.

When I edit reStructuredText, I have

```
iskeyword=38,42,43,45,47-58,60-62,64-90,97-122,_
```

That explains why the umlauts are not marked, but I do not understand where this comes from. When I just open gVim this is set to

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
```

Where could this be coming from?

Comment: Put `set encoding=utf-8` in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: That is already in my `.vim/vimrc` and `:set enc?` gives me `utf-8`. Same with `fenc`. Still it does not work.

Comment: After `:set iskeyword&` is `ü` still not recognized as a part of a word?

Comment: Show as your iskeyword (`set iskeyword`). It should be something like `"@,48-57,_,128-167,224-235"`or `"@,48-57,_,192-255"`. Are you using Vim or Vi ? (the default value in Vi (`"@,48-57,_"`) does not recognize ü; the default value in Vim is fine)

Comment: I use gVim and have `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`. It magically works in a fresh Vim instance now. That is strange, I have to observe that more carefully.

Comment: When editing certain documents this happens. I updated the question.

Comment: When you type `:verb set isk`, does it tell you from where the option was set ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@` character in `iskeyword` includes all characters for which `isalpha()` (C function) is TRUE; in modern (last 20 years) libc implementations this also looks for unicode characters.

Your second `iskeyword` uses `97-122` (a-z) and `64-90` (A-Z), which doesn't include all the variants with the various diacritics (such as the umlaut/diaeresis/trema).

So the solution is to replace `97-122` and `64-90` with `@`.

This funky `iskeyword` comes from the LISP syntax file; the `rst` syntax file includes a bunch of other syntax files for highlighting the code blocks.

Luckily you can set which languages to include with the `g:rst_syntax_code_list` variable. The default is:

```
let g:rst_syntax_code_list = ['vim', 'java', 'cpp', 'lisp', 'php', 'python', 'perl']
```

Since it's unlikely that you need LISP syntax highlighting in your reStructuredText file, you can probably just remove it. Just add it anywhere in your vimrc file, if it's defined, the syntax file will use that value instead of defining its own.

In my opinion, you probably want to use:

```
let g:rst_syntax_code_list = []
```

Because who knows what funky side-effects the other syntax files cause...

Comment: Cool, thank you! This did not happen to me on Ubuntu so far, it only has happened here on Fedora 22. Probably their syntax files are a bit different. It works now.

Comment: The hint with the `@` standing for alphanumerical characters was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If one inlines grammars from other languages in for example markdown files, then the settings of those languages seem to override the settings for markdown syntax. One can check if that is the case using:

```
:verbose set iskeyword?
```

In order to fix this, one can define an auto command to be run each time one enters a markdown file (and probably other languages as well):

```
autocmd BufEnter,BufNewFile *.md set iskeyword=38,42,43,45,47-58,60-62,_,@
```

Putting this in my `.vimrc` fixed the issue for me. I was using `vim-pandoc` syntax and inlined languages including `racket`, `python`, `sh` and some. I think it is not necessary to define an auto command for leaving markdown files, because when you enter files of other languages, their syntax files should set their keywords, if I understand correctly.